# Trying to split a large string in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, split

I'm trying to split a large string as:

```
string='<tr id="section1">98811</tr><tr id="section2">109148</tr><tr id="section3">30818</tr>'
```

I want to get the number (109148)

Comment: provide some more details..

Comment: I'm doing a bash script and I want to get the number "109148" with a split for the string.

Comment: On the variable $string

Comment: and how do you distinguish 109148 from 98811, for example? what id do you require? what is your final goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
echo $string|grep -oP '(?<="section2">).*?(?=</tr>)'
```

Here will be the **output** exactly,

```
109148
```

---

I used **section2** to extract value of that particular `tr` tag for others, you needed to change the id/name of element to get different values.

Comment: I didn't know `grep` supports non-greedy search. (`sed` doesn't.) Thanks for the info..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`.

```
echo $string | sed 's/.*="section2">\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/'
```